# What does the phrase "Vietnam, the mixture of up and down" mean?

Tags: war, vietnam-war, vietnam

I bought this lighter today and it's supposed to be in the style of what soldiers fighting in Vietnam carried. I don't understand the quote on the back, though.

[image: Lighter front]

[image: lighter back]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Dong Ap Bia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dong_Ap_Bia) is a mountain in [Vietnam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam).

Since the lighter has the dates (19)65-66, it was probably used (and engraved) by a soldier stationed in support of the [Montagnards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degar) who lived in and around the area.

In that area of Vietnam there were no straight, flat roads, and in fact no roads at all. So every where a soldier had to go they did it up and down (the mountains.)